# How to convert DFA to NFA with fewer states and build TG from DFA with two states?

Tags: automata

Consider the following NFA:
[image: drawing of a NFA]

(i)  Build a DFA with as few states as possible that accepts exactly the same language as the NFA above.
(ii) Build a TG (transition graph) with 2 states that accepts exactly the same language as the NFA above.

Correct me if I'm wrong; below is my answer.
[image: drawing of a NFA with fewer states and TG with two states]

My answer is inspired by the answer to my previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3714679/how-to-convert-finite-automaton-fa-to-non-deterministic-fa-nfa-with-fewer-st/3715010#3715010). I'm not sure if this is correct and will be grateful for your input.

Than you.

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: sweet :) this was my first try after getting the answer (explanation) from @IlkkaTörmä.